# Error 415. Service REST with Spring - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, json, spring

I have a problem with my service. I am sending a petition $http.get from angular to my Spring controller, but i have the next error : The server refused this request because the requested party is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/person", consumes = {"application/json;charset=UTF-8"}, produces={"application/json;charset=UTF-8"},  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Person> listPersons_() {
        return this.personService.listPersons();
    }
...
```

**Angular Service:**

```
    function get($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('person').
            success(function(data) {
                $scope.greeting = data;
            });
    }
...
```

**Screenshot:**
 [image: Console]

**Header:**
 [image: Headers]

Comment: Seems like you are missing `/` & controller name to while making ajax, it should be `$http.get('/Person/person')`

Comment: It's okay. I checked the console

Comment: Can u put a screenshot of you request headers here?

Comment: I edited my question with a screenshot of the console

Comment: Try turning up the logging level for org.springframework.web to DEBUG. This additional logging often gives some useful clues when I get errors like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ... after removing the atributes (consume and produces), I would get an error 406, and I felt I needed to add the Jackson-databin library. and it worked.

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Person> listPersons_() {
        return this.personService.listPersons();
    }
...
```

**Dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC is not very verbose by default when it comes to HTTP errors. What you can do is raise the log level of the package `org.springframework.web` to `DEBUG` so you can get a better explanation of the 415 error.

Best of luck !

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need those `produces/consumes` headers. I had developed a very similar application which had the AngularJS service the same as yours, but it was relatively very simple on the Spring end:

```
// List All Employees
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public AllEmployeesResponse listAllEmployees() {

    return empService.listAll();
}
```

All I had was a `AllEmployeesResponse` object containing a list of `Employee` objects.

The json took care of itself. If yours is not, check if you have implemented `Serializable` in your `@Entity` class.

Also, mine had a `@RestController` instead of a plain `@Controller`.